# drf-yasg: How to hide Django rest Framework schema?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

I use [drf_yasg swagger](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_spec.html) for my Django API.
I would like to know how to easily disable the schema and model.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nh7k.png)

here is my code:

```html
from .models import Articles
from .serializers import ArticlesSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication,TokenAuthentication, BasicAuthentication
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema
from drf_yasg import openapi


@swagger_auto_schema(methods=['get'], operation_description="description", manual_parameters=[
    openapi.Parameter('category', openapi.IN_QUERY, "category1, category2, category3", type=openapi.TYPE_STRING),
    openapi.Parameter('name', openapi.IN_QUERY, "full name", type=openapi.TYPE_STRING),
], responses={
    200: openapi.Response('Response', ArticlesSerializer),
}, tags=['Articles'])

# desactivate POST methode on swagger
@swagger_auto_schema(method='POST', auto_schema=None)

@api_view(['GET','POST'])   
def articles(request):
    """
    List all articles.
    """
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            articles = Articles.objects.all()
            serializer = ArticlesSerializer(Articles, many=True)
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

        elif request.method == 'POST':
            data = JSONParser().parse(request)
            serializer = ArticlesSerializer(data=data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
            return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
    return JsonResponse({"status":"403", "message":"User not authenticated"})
```

If i add this

```
class UserList(APIView):
swagger_schema = None
```

i got error:

```
AssertionError: `method` or `methods` can only be specified on @action or @api_view views
```

Code Edited:
the articles function is pretty simple nothing related to the API, only Python code.

Here the views Class is also pretty simple.

**Class Views:**

```
from django.db import models

class Articles(models.Model):
STATUS = (
   (1, 'PENDING'),
   (2, 'COMPLETED'),
   (3, 'DECLINED'),
   (0, 'BANNED'),
)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
...
status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
   choices = STATUS,
   default = 1,
)
```

Comment: Can you give a full coed of your class view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out.
I just had to overwrite the responses parameter with either plain text, markdown or html.

```
@swagger_auto_schema(methods=['get'], operation_description="Get article information ", manual_parameters=[
    openapi.Parameter('id', openapi.IN_QUERY, "Article Id", type=openapi.TYPE_STRING),
], responses={ 200: '**Example:** \
  <div class="highlight-code"><pre>{  <br>\
  "category": "string", <br>\
  "image": "string",<br>\
  "link": "string",<br>\
  "birth_date": "string",<br>\
}</pre></div>'},
tags=['Get Articles'])
```

To have the same css effect (background black) you can add this custom CSS in the file ...\site-packages\drf_yasg\static\drf-yasg\style.css

```
.swagger-ui .markdown .highlight-code pre{
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  background: #41444e;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I only have half of the answer, to disable Models I added this to my `setting.py`

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'DEFAULT_FIELD_INSPECTORS': [
        'drf_yasg.inspectors.CamelCaseJSONFilter',
        'drf_yasg.inspectors.InlineSerializerInspector',
        'drf_yasg.inspectors.RelatedFieldInspector',
        'drf_yasg.inspectors.ChoiceFieldInspector',
        'drf_yasg.inspectors.FileFieldInspector',
        'drf_yasg.inspectors.DictFieldInspector',
        'drf_yasg.inspectors.SimpleFieldInspector',
        'drf_yasg.inspectors.StringDefaultFieldInspector',
    ],
}
```

Credit goes to [this guys](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/issues/281), and here is [the documentation](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/settings.html#default-field-inspectors) for more details.

Comment: i tried this but still not working, i even add ```ref_name = None``` to the Meta class of ```Class ArticlesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)```.
For now i'm using custom js to remove the node element onload, but still looking for better solution.